# Pass variable and its contents from workspace to GUI function in MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab, variables, workspace

I have a variable in the MATLAB workspace and I want to pass the variable name and its contents to a function in my GUI.

How do I achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *totally* sure what you mean when you say "pass the variable name and its contents", but here's one possible solution. After you pass a set of data to a function like so:

```
some_function(data);  %# Pass the variable "data" to a function
```

You can get the variable name of the input argument from inside the function using [INPUTNAME](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/inputname.html):

```
function some_function(inputArgument)
  name = inputname(1);  %# Will return "data" as the name of the input variable
end
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out in a comment by High Performance Mark, the variable `inputArgument` inside the function will contain the *values* stored in the variable `data` in the workspace of the caller.

Comment: and the value of the passed variable is passed to become the value of the dummy argument, in this case inputArgument.  Just in case that wasn't obvious.

Comment: Thank you all, I found a way of passing the variable to a function using eval

Answer (score 0):

If this question is related to your other most recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765084/get-dimensions-for-dataset-matlab-size-function), then why not build the operation into your GUI? You can use guide to create a pushbutton, and place the code under the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have created the figure with GUI using the GUIDE, and that you know the 'Tag' names of the GUI objects.

((1)) Open the figure using the GUIDE, ((2)) Open the Property Inspector for the figure (select the background, the light-gray gridded area of the figure, and double-click over it, to make the Property Inspector for the figure to pop-up), ((3)) Turn the 'HandleVisibility' 'on' (by default, it may be set as 'callback'), ((4)) Save the figure and close the GUIDE, and finally ((5)) set the GUI property values from the MATLAB Console (or "Command Window") using some parameters that are currently available on your workspace.

I hope this helps.

Best,
Y.T.